# No hard drive detected on compaq presario m2000 (IDE hard disk)

Tags: hard-drive, bios, pata, hard-drive-failure, compaq-laptop

My laptop crashed. At first I thought it was a hard disk problem. I bought a new one but the computer keeps telling me that no hard drive is detected.

I have tried to install Windows XP SP2/3, windows7, Ubuntu and Fedora but I still get the same problem.

I have a tough time with this laptop and I just can't figure out what is wrong with it.  Every other component seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Is the new hard drive detected in the bios? How big (gigabytes) is the new drive compared to the old one?

Comment: If the BIOS does not detect the hard disk then you can give up on installing. It is a bit like saying I can not find the tank in a car and I tried filling it with both leaded and unleaded, but I still can not find the place to put the fuel. --- First solve why the BIOS does not detect the drive. After that you can install an OS.

Comment: the old one was a 40gb ide hdd and i got a new one with the same capacity.

Comment: @Hennes that is what i'm trying to do so i need help on that part(solving the bios issue) because i know after solving that every other thing will be just fine

Comment: It might be a fault on the motherboard or the IDE connector. Do you have something else to plug in those drives? E.g. An external 2.5" PATA to USB caddy? Or another laptop? That could rule out disk problems (even your original drive could be fine).

Comment: what i have can't take ide's only SATA...my other laptop is not as old as the presario so what do i do after i get the pata to usb caddy?

Comment: You plug the old drive(s) in the PATA to USB case and try to read the data from them on a computer. Not nessecary the on the Compaq.

Comment: It sounds like the drive ribbon might be damaged. These tend to be a plastic film and are really easy to damage.

Answer (score -3):

check very carefully how the hard drive is plugged in.
the hard drive plugs into a connector which plugs into the motherboard.
i have a similar problem all the time.
in the end i bought some double sided sticky tape
and just taped the hard drive to the motherboard.

Comment: That is a very dangerous thing to do - think electrical short circuits.

Comment: Unless you are covering the entire drive in tape to insulate it this suggestion should be avoided. I should also mention covering the entire drive in tape may lead to cooling issues.

Comment: If it is HDD, there is at least one hole what says specifically "Do not cover". https://superuser.com/questions/368774/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-holes-marked-do-not-cover-on-hard-drives. This is a horrible advice of yours.