# Is it ok to band HDD in a completely non-ventilated cellophane?

Tags: hard-drive

I wanted to wrap-up the hdd tightly into such material:

[image]

However, it will completely block all areas (i remember that there could be some holes on hdd) and is it ok, if will be in complete non-ventilation and it can't get any air? (btw, it will be working 8 hours a day, with connected usb-line).

Comment: Lack of ventilation is not a vacuum.

Comment: What is your rational for doing this? There is probably a better, commercial product intended for your application.

Comment: @grawity yeap, sorry :)

Comment: @acejavelin you are right absolutely. Just at the moment of doing something, i didnt have time to purchase anything and wahtever was near me, i wanted to use that. However, you are right completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two concerns with placing a mechanical hard disk in a *completely* air tight plastic enclosure:

1. **Heat.** If your enclosure traps the heat generated by the drive it will fail much more rapidly. Most drives need to be kept below 80 degrees Fahrenheit (your specific drive will state its operating range).
2. **Air pressure.** Mechanical drives have a [small hole](https://superuser.com/q/368774/213131) in their case that allows the drive's internal air pressure to adjust to changes in the surrounding environment's air pressure. Depending on how how rigid your enclosure is, how tightly it is sealed and how much or little air it has in it, this function could be impeded. As a consequence your drive could experience head crashes due to improper internal air pressure.

Comment: Air pressure is not an issue as long as the outer container is not rigid. The outer container will simply deform until inner and outer pressures reach an equilibrium. (Side note: don't put this underwater. Water pressure rises a lot faster than air.)

Comment: @Bob Edited to account for rigidity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Static electricity is another concern.  I can't tell from the picture if the hard drive has an enclosure or just brown tape (bad screen on my part).  If you just put an HD with exposed electronics into a bag that isn't explicitly non-static, then static will build up from vibrations.  A spark in the wrong place can abruptly render the HD unusable, so ensure you have nightly offsite backups.

Comment: wow, nice catch.